# Making "Thank You" slide in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, beamer

How to make a slide with "Thank You" on the middle, I've tried this:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
Thank You
\end {center}
\end{frame}
```

But it didn't work and the error appeared.

Also when I tried something like this:

```
## Title
\begin{center}
Thank You
\end {center}
```

I don't know how to remove the title.

Comment: please make a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

If only centering without a slide title is what you want, you can simply make an empty heading with `##`, see below:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Name"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Singapore"
    colortheme: "seagull"
    fonttheme: "serif"

fontsize: 16pt
---


## Slide 1
text

## Slide 2

##
\begin{center}
Thank You
\end {center}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Minimal reproduce example:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Name"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Singapore"
    colortheme: "seagull"
    fonttheme: "serif"

fontsize: 16pt
---


## Slide 1
text

## Slide 2
# hear I want to have a sign "Thank You" on the middle of the page, what I've tried is in my question:

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
Thank You
\end {center}
\end{frame}
```